# DRF ImageField Inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Django API with DRF. I have a custom User Model like this :

**models.py :**

```py
from typing import Type, List
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

from main.apps.user.managers import UserManager


def to_profile_picture(instance: "User", filename: str) -> str:
    return f"profile_pictures/{instance.email}/{uuid4()}_{filename}"


class User(AbstractBaseUser, TimeStampedModel, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email Address"), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        _("First Name"), max_length=128, blank=True, null=True
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last Name"), max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(_("Display Name"), max_length=128)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_("Active"), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_("Is staff"), default=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=to_profile_picture, null=True, blank=True
    )

    objects: Type[UserManager] = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD: str = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS: List[str] = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name: str = _("User")
        verbose_name_plural: str = _("Users")

    @property
    def get_full_name(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

**managers.py :**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given email must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email: str, password: str = None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

**viewsets.py :**

```py
from typing import Type
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.decorators import action

from main.apps.user.models import User
from main.apps.user.serializers import UserSerializer


class UsersViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
        """
        if self.action == "create":
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        else:
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class: Type[UserSerializer] = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer: UserSerializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            serializer.validated_data.pop("email"),
            serializer.validated_data.pop("password"),
            **serializer.validated_data,
        )
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, data=UserSerializer(user).data)

    @action(detail=False)
    def me(self, request: Request):
        return Response(
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=UserSerializer(request.user).data
        )
```

serializers.py :

```py
from typing import Type, Tuple, Dict, Any

from rest_framework import serializers

from main.apps.user.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model: Type[User] = User
        fields: Tuple[str] = (
            "id",
            "email",
            "password",
            "display_name",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "profile_picture",
        )
        extra_kwargs: Dict[str, Any] = {"password": {"write_only": True}}
```

My issue here is that when I go to the route I defined for the `UserViewset` and trigger the `list` action, it returns the full URL with the `http://domain/` in front of the file path, which is actually exactly what I want. But on the `/me` route or the `create` route, only the path is returned, without the domain.

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the context that is not passed to the serializer in custom routes, but might be in the default `ModelViewset` routes.

If anyone knows how I can replicate the list action behavior on my other routes, I'll be glad !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found out that it was what I thought, I just needed to pass the request as context to my serializer.

Change the method `me` in file `viewsets.py` from that :

```py
@action(detail=False)
    def me(self, request: Request):
        return Response(
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=UserSerializer(request.user).data
        )
```

to this :

```py
@action(detail=False)
    def me(self, request: Request):
        return Response(
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            data=UserSerializer(request.user, context={"request": request}).data,
        )
```